# Why did Jigsaw choose Zep in Saw?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw

In [Saw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_%28film%29), at the end of the movie we learn that Zep was forced to hold the Gordons captive to obtain an antidote for the slow-acting poison in his body. However, this scene confuses me, because **Zep hasn't done anything wrong to Jigsaw**. He was just an attendant to him.

Why did Jigsaw poison Zep?

Why did Jigsaw choose Zep to hold the Gordons captive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [**Sawpedia**](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Zep_Hindle):

> Zep formed a sort of bond with John [Kramer] while he was being treated, but was considered to have "issues of his own" by him. Zep talked about the doctors behind their backs, saying that they were all having affairs and calling Dr. Lawrence Gordon a cold-hearted bastard.
>
> John seemed to see a lot of his own actions in Zep's goals, reminding him of himself before he was diagnosed with cancer.
>
> **The reason why John decided to test Zep was because the former noticed that Zep was wasting his life with dreams of becoming a doctor, dreams that were never going to come true**. 
> [[Saw: Rebirth](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Saw:_Rebirth)]